# How to import .csv file in defined table in command line?

Tags: php, database, apache2, xampp, linux

I need to **import.csv** file throught windows command line terminal in defined table.

I was trying this command :

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -p dbname dbtablename < C:\xampp\htdocs\site\csvfolder\import.csv
```

But it does not works. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use LOAD DATA INFILE for csv files. See here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html.

You can run it from the command line like so:

```
mysql -u root dbname -p -e "load data infile 'c:/path/to/file.csv' into table dbtablename"
```

Comment: so there is no terminal solution...need to work in mysql anyway ?

Comment: Try: mysql -u root -p dbname -e "load data infile 'c:/path/to/file.csv' into table dbtablename". I edited my answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

Please put your CSV file in the same location where you run the command and try again.

> (like : c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql\import.csv)

```
c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -p database_name table_name < import.csv
```